# Why wont my Collection View take the whole width of the Frame. .net MAUI

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

Ive been trying to make a simple scoring app for a card game that i play. And ive just veen trying to get the basic structure. So i created a Frame with a collection view with some mock data to represent the players in the columns in my XAML. I want the columns to fill up all of the horizontal space if there is any and then it will automatically scroll if there is more. However I cannot get my columns to spread out to take the whole width when there is only 2 for example. I'm using .net MAUI with .net 8. Any help would be more than appreciated! Here is my code. I did not really make any significant changes to the base project creation start up and have mainly been working on the generated MainPage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BlitzScorer.MainPage">




    <ScrollView Padding="10">
        <Frame VerticalOptions="Start" CornerRadius="20" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" Padding="10" >
            <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*">
                <CollectionView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                         HorizontalItemSpacing="5"  />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                            <x:String>Player 1</x:String>
                            <x:String>Player 2</x:String>
                        </x:Array>
                    </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Text="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="Beige" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </ScrollView>
    

</ContentPage>
```

Ive tried using the FillAndExpand attribute on multiple areas but the CollectionView just does not want to take the space no matter what.

Comment: Get rid of the Grid and the ScrollView, or make the grid fill its own parent container

Comment: Do not use Frame. Use Border instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the community has pointed out, you can remove the `Grid` and the `ScrollView` which will fill up all of the horizontal space automatically. Also, you may need use `Border` rather than `Frame` as the Border is much more flexible under this circumstance. For instance, you can give each corner an individual corner radius.

Here's the XAML code below for your reference:

```
<Border VerticalOptions="Start"  BackgroundColor="LightGreen" Padding="10" >
        <Border.StrokeShape>
               <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="20,20,20,20"/>
         </Border.StrokeShape>

           <CollectionView  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalItemSpacing="5"  />

            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemsSource>

                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">

                    <x:String>Player 1</x:String>

                    <x:String>Player 2</x:String>

                </x:Array>

            </CollectionView.ItemsSource>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="Beige"/>

                </DataTemplate>

            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

      </CollectionView>
</Border>
```